# change animated image background using imagemagick

Tags: bash, image, imagemagick

I'm trying to fill the background of a gif using imagemagick,
[this is the input file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DoIke.gif)
I was able of cropping the background
[still not perfect but it's an acceptable result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e1Pew.gif)
Now when I try to fill the background:
[the output is static despite being a gif](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zt5yt.gif)
This is the command I tried :

```
convert "$1" -resize 400x400  -gravity center -background "pink" -extent 400x400 "out.gif"
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what you are trying to do, but this should show you how to replace the background using [floodfill](https://imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php#floodfill):

```
magick crybaby.gif -coalesce -fuzz 10% -fill yellow -floodfill 0x0 "rgb(251,102,90)" result.gif
```

[image]